# Why Button don't works in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, uibutton, user-input

I have a Pause Menu in a little game in Unity and have been testing it in different scenes, so I used a prefab. The problem appears in a playable scene. I have attached the function Resume to a Button but nothing happens. It is like the button is a panel or an image.

```
public class PauseBehavior : MonoBehaviour{
    
    Canvas menu;
    bool pause;

    void Start(){
        menu = GetComponent<Canvas>();
        menu.enabled = false;
    }
    void Update(){
        Pause();
    }

    public void Pause(){   
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("p")){
            pause = !pause;  
            menu.enabled = pause;  
            if (pause){
                Time.timeScale = 0f;
            }
            else{
                Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }



    public void ContinueGame(){
        menu.enabled = !pause;
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Ps: Sorry for my writing, but this is my first question and english is a foreign language for me.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. When you click the "Resume" button are you expecting it to call PauseBehaviour.ContinueGame()? If so, if you put a breakpoint in that function, does it ever get hit?

Comment: You say you have attatched the function `Resume` to your scene button, but the script you have posted doesn't seem to have this `Resume` function implemented, could you add the relevant code and a screenshot of your button in the inspector?

Comment: You code looks fine. I would check if you connected your Resume Button with the Continue function? Also what happens if you change `menu.enabled = !pause;` from `ContinueGame()` to `menu.enabled = false;`

Comment: @Remy the Resume Function is ContinueGame(). @MathewHD , yeah, I connected. I resolved it. I had a littel problem with Event System.It didn't work for some reason. And thanks for the advice. I changed ``menu.enabled = !pause;`` to ``pause = false; `` and ``menu.enabled = pause;``